# Ordered selection from a dropdown

Tags: codeigniter-2

I want to create an ordered list from a multiple select dropdown list, issue is the select option input provided by html only orders values picked linearly, but I want it ordered according to the order I select them at. So I decided to use some JS to do the trick but wsnt able to hack. Here's the code. Help out please!!

```
    <script language="'javascript'">
  function showselection()
  {
    var frm = document.testing
    var opt = frm.testsel

    var numofoptions = opt.length
    var selValue = new Array

    var j = 0
    for (i=0; i<numofoptions; i++)
    {
      if (opt[i].selected === true)
      {
        selValue[j] = opt[i].value
        j++
      }
    }

    selValue = selValue.join("+")

    document.getElementById("txtEditions").innerHTML = selValue
  }
</script>

<form method=POST name='testing'>
  <select name='testsel' multiple onchange='showselection()'>
    <option value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
    <option value="three">three</option>
  </select>
  <textarea id="txtEditions"></textarea>
</form>
```

how do i make sure the order of selection is saved and not the order from the source of the dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codeigniter has a form helper for [form_dropdown](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html) / form_multiselect this allows you pass an array to the helper function to create the html.  you can order the array before parsing it to this function with an array sorting function, like [ksort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) or [asort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) depending on your data.

sorry I can't be of more help because I am not clear exactly what you need to do.  if you literally want to save the order, then that means saving it in a database structure in some way.

Comment: The issue is lets say i have option1. option2 and option3 vith respective values of 1,2,3...if i select option3, option1,and option2 in that order, i need the values to save to the database in 3,1,2 order...at the moment, it will save 1,2,3...irrespective of my order of selection

Comment: a select widget is not the best way to do it then. semantically you are talking about an ordered list.  so use that, order the list of items on the screen using the awesomely cool jquery draggable widget. see here.http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable send that ordered list object to the database for storing. i suggest you have a list of objects to order one container, then an ordered list in another.  users drag the items they want in the list and order them as required.